# Drop down menu load with specific value selected

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, drop-down-menu

I have a form which allows a user to edit a record. One of the items in the form is a drop down menu populated with values from a database. I was wondering if there were a way to set the default value of the drop down to the value held in the database for that record instead of automatically just going to the first item in the list (I am hoping this makes sense).

```
<td><label for ="genre">Image Genre: </label></td>
<td><select name="genre">
   <?php echo'<option value="'. $row['genreID'] .'">'. $row['genreName'] .'</option>'; ?>
   <?php while($genre_item = mysqli_fetch_array($genre_sql)){
   echo'<option value="'. $genre_item['id'] .'">'. $genre_item['genreName'] .'</option>';
         }
   ?>
</select></td>
```

As you can see I have put an option in to populate the first value with the value held in the database. The problem with this is that the *genreName* then appears twice.

Are there any solutions to this?

Answer (score 0):

```
<td><label for ="genre">Image Genre: </label></td>
<td><select name="genre">

<?php $genre_item = mysqli_fetch_array($genre_sql); ?>
<?php foreach($genre_item as $item){
 echo'<option value="'. $item['id'] .'">'. $item['genreName'] .'</option>';
 }
 ?>

</select>
</td>
```

**if i understood you right ....**

Answer (score 0):

*<sub>Bearing in mind this question is more than two years old, it doesn't have an accepted answer...</sub>*

Use the HTML tag [`<option>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option) attribute *selected*:

> **selected**
>   If present, this Boolean attribute indicates that the option is initially selected. If the  element is the descendant of a  element whose [multiple](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select#attr-multiple) attribute is not set, only one single  of this  element may have the selected attribute.<sup>[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option)</sup>

Integrating this with the PHP code:

```
<?php while($genre_item = mysqli_fetch_array($genre_sql)){
$selected = '';
//modify this condition per your needs - 
if ($genre_item['id'] == $row['genreID') {
    $selected = 'selected';
}   
echo'<option value="'. $genre_item['id'] .'" '.$selected.'>'. $genre_item['genreName'] .'</option>';
```

When the selected option is found, the output should appear like below:

```html
<label for ="genre">Image Genre: </label><br />
<select name="genre">
<option value="ind">Indie</option>
<option value="rock" selected>Rock</option>
<option value="srock">Soft Rock</option>
<option value="tech">Techno</option>
</select>
```

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option</sub>